# Call MapReduce from Local a web app

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sandbox

I have a web app deploy in my localhost.
Also I have a MapReduce job (cleandata.jar) in a hortonworks sandbox in my pc.

How can I call from my web app to my MapReduce .jar?

I'm trying with  JSch  y Channel Exec to do this in order to perform a call system to the virtual machine and this works. There are a more elegant/easy form to do this?

Comment: I haven't really seen too many web apps that kick off map/reduce jobs since most m/r jobs don't run at interactive speeds. A typical pattern is to run your analytic at whatever interval makes sense and store the results in a data store for the web app to do any final aggregations and display.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Hortonworks Sandbox but the proper way of launching Yarn (and MapReduce) applications programmatically is by using `YarnClient` java class. It's quite complicated tough because you need to know some Hadoop internals to do that. First, you should have network access to ResourceManager, NodeManagers, DataNodes and NameNode. Next you should set [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) properties according to `hdfs-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` files you will probably find in the sandbox (you can copy them and put them into classpath of your webapp).

You can take a look here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html

Note that if your cluster is secured, webapp from which you will submit the job have to be run on [Java with extended security (JCE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and you should authenticate using `UserGroupInformation`.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. So, if I use YarnClient and cofigure properly the configurations properties, can I put my mapreduce .jar in my host?